# Get subtitles from youtube video using video.google.com - text format

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api, dotnet-httpclient

I want to get subtitles from a youtube video. When I write in the url "http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=Dceyy0cX6J4&fmt=srv3" the text is as expected, but when I use C# the text has some characters with the &#39 ; (example)

The c# code is pretty simple:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient)
{      
 var response = client.GetString("http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=Dceyy0cX6J4&fmt=srv3")

}
```

Is there any way to add a format header? How could I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is [url encoded content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).
You will need to decode this.

Luckily you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(response)` from `System.Web` and this will give you a perfect readable response

Answer (score 0):

Check out the URLEncode method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2